# Cannot append multiple elements into a array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic2

This is the array "serviceSubCatNamesToListToSet" which I need to updated

```
{
"serviceTypes": [
    {
        "service_type_id": 1,
        "service_type_name": "Washing",
        "service_type_price": "3000.00",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "pivot": {
            "service_service_type_service_id": 1,
            "service_service_type_service_type_id": 1
        }
    }
 ]
}
```

And I need to append a array object called "technicianData" into above(serviceSubCatNamesToListToSet) array.

The way I'm appending "technicianData"

```
  this.toServiceSubCatNamesList[this.technicianIndex]['technicianData'] = this.technicianData;
```

After append "serviceSubCatNamesToListToSet" will look like this.

```
serviceSubCatNamesToListToSet:
   > Object
     created_at:null
     pivot:Object
     service_type_id:1
     service_type_name:"Washing"
     service_type_price:"3000.00"
     >technicianData:Object
                 created_at:null
                 technician_address:"Colombo 05"
                 technician_code:"T0001"
                 technician_id:1
                 technician_name:"Brian Adams"
                 technician_tel1:"312252937"
```

So far it's working.But when I'm trying to add multiple elements into "serviceSubCatNamesToListToSet.technicianData" It's not working.

Any suggestions to overcome this issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `serviceTypes` is  the original json array,`serviceTypes[0]` will allow to get the first object

```js
var serviceTypes= [{
  "service_type_id": 1,
  "service_type_name": "Washing",
  "service_type_price": "3000.00",
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null,
  "pivot": {
    "service_service_type_service_id": 1,
    "service_service_type_service_type_id": 1
  }
}]
var technicianData = [1,2,3];
serviceTypes[0].technicianData=technicianData;
console.log(serviceTypes)
```